# prevent following svg link in joints diagram

Tags: javascript, svg, preventdefault, jointjs

I want to prevent a link of a cell by some conditions in jointjs:

```
paper.on({'cell:pointerclick': function(cellView, event, x, y) {
    if (!cellView.model.isLink()) {
        if (condition) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}});
```

This is working for a click on the cell. But if I move an element, the link will be opened after the movement (pointerup).

The markup is something like:

```
<a><g class="rotatable"><g class="scalable"><rect class="body"/></g><text class="label"/></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand your question but, if you want to be able to test an attempted link between two elements before you permit it to be added to the graph, you want to use validateConnection(). It's defined on the API page under joint.dia.Paper options. Here is the link:

[API page](http://jointjs.com/api#joint.dia.Paper:options)

You can also see examples of the validation function in action on the Working with Ports tutorial, here:

[Working with Ports tutorial](http://jointjs.com/tutorial/ports)